# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0:

Tags: java, android, xml

I don't know why my app is crashing, if someone can help me, I would be very thankful.
Here is my main_activity, and the problem isn't with VIDEO_ID.

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "I HIDE MY API";  

    private String VIDEO_ID;  

    private AdView mAdView; 

    private Button skipbtn;

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;`


       `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //initializing Youtube Player View
            YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
            youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
            MobileAds.initialize(this,
                    "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

            //PUB
            mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            //FIN PUB

            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {

                }
            });

            skipbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skipbtn);
            skipbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }

                }
            });
        }



        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            VIDEO_ID= new VIDEO_ID().getMes_Videos();
            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
            youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
            if (!b)
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failure to initialize", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaying() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPaused() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopped() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBuffering(boolean b) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekTo(int i) {

            }
        };

        private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoading() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdStarted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoStarted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoEnded() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

            }
        };
}
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="piano.music.com.musicpiano">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to past the log error that contains the crash report, also your main activity xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the xml file.
You probably wrong the declaration of some custom object, in line 0 of the corresponding XML what is there? 
Is there any object declared wrong? com.XXX.yyy .... check.